# Is this a correct way to represent this likelihood function?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, likelihood

Supposed we have a regression of the form,

\begin{equation}
y_t=\beta'x_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t
\end{equation} 
where the erros possess zero median conditional on the past information - i.e.$P[\varepsilon_t<0\mid\mathcal{I}_{t-1}]=P[\varepsilon_t\geq0\mid\mathcal{I}_{t-1}]=0.5$ and the signs are defined as $R_t=1$ for $y_t\geq 0$ and $R_t=0$ otherwise for $t=1,\cdots,T$, where $\mathcal{I}_{t}=[x_0,\cdots,x_t]'$ is an information vector, such that $\mathcal{I}_s\subset\mathcal{I}_t$ for $s<t$.

Now given the model, suppose under the null hypothesis that $H_0:\beta=0$, we wish to express the likelihood function in terms of the signs $R_1,\cdots,R_T$ conditional on the aforementioned information vector. As the signs are Bernoulli variables and given the assumptions on the errors, I was hoping to end up in a situation, where the joint likelihood conditional on the past information can be expressed as

\begin{equation}
P[R_1=r_1\mid \mathcal{I}_0]\times  P[R_2=r_2\mid \mathcal{I}_1]\times\cdots\times P[R_T=r_T\mid \mathcal{I}_{T-1}]=\\ 
P[y_1\geq0\mid \mathcal{I}_0]^{R_1}P[y_1<0\mid \mathcal{I}_0]^{1-R_1}\times P[y_2\geq0\mid \mathcal{I}_1]^{R_2}P[y_2<0\mid \mathcal{I}_1]^{1-R_2}\times\cdots\times P[y_T\geq0\mid \mathcal{I}_1]^{R_T}P[y_T<0\mid \mathcal{I}_1]^{1-R_T} 
\end{equation}

so that under the null hypothesis and because of the assumption on the errors, I would end up with

\begin{equation}
P[\varepsilon_1\geq0\mid \mathcal{I}_0]^{R_1}P[\varepsilon_1<0\mid \mathcal{I}_0]^{1-R_1}\times P[\varepsilon_2\geq0\mid \mathcal{I}_1]^{R_2}P[\varepsilon_2<0\mid \mathcal{I}_1]^{1-R_2}\times\cdots\times P[\varepsilon_T\geq0\mid \mathcal{I}_1]^{R_T}P[\varepsilon_T<0\mid \mathcal{I}_1]^{1-R_T}=0.5^T 
\end{equation}

Is there anyway to accomplish this? Because if each term in the joint-likelihood function is conditioned on the entire information vector $\mathcal{I}_{T-1}$, then probabilities do not coincide with the assumption on the errors, and the final result as I have written cannot be achieved.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you for your response. I have included the details for my question and have further changed from the dependent case to independent just for the sake of convenience. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: To avoid confusing your audience, you should refer to the terms $\varepsilon_t$ as "errors" or, perhaps, "perturbations," because a *residual* is defined to be the difference between an observation and its predicted value.  The $\varepsilon_t$ are not residuals in this conventional sense.

Comment: @whuber Thank you! I have edited the question.